# Querying Related Records using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have two databases:
- A list of tower sites.
- A list of access points, on those sites. (Some sites don't have access points).

So say I have `sites` (`A`, `B`, `C`) which have `site_id`'s of `1`, `2`, `3`.

Site `A` has `3` access points, `B` has `4`, and `C` has `0`.

So I want a table that only returns the sites that have access points. So A and B should only be returned.

I have a model for each that has all their information and links them via ID in Sites and site_id in AccessPoints.

What would be a good query to run using Eloquent?

Right now I'm running:

```
$sites = Sites::with(['AccessPoints' => function($query) { 
$query->where('status', '=', 'production');
}])
->with('AccessPoints.Associations')
->orderBy('name', 'asc')
->get();
```

Just to give some insight. The status being production is what tells the database whether or not the access point still exists and is being used. So production means it exists still. So any sites that don't have access points with a production status shouldn't show.

The with(AccessPoints.Associations) is a second query that links a third table to get the number of people using each access point which is working correctly. But the first part of the query isn't. I'm still getting sites with aps that are decommissioned or don't have aps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query will give you all access points because you do not have has condition. Following would give you the result you want :

```
<?php 

$sites = Sites::whereHas('AccessPoints', function($q){
    $q->where('status', '=', 'production');
})
->with('AccessPoints.Associations')
->orderBy('name', 'asc')
->get();
```